# How can I delete overlapping faces when the faces are in multiple objects?

Tags: faces

I've already seen the Remove Doubles method, but as far as I know it only removes the doubled vertices...
Plus, the overlapping faces are from two different objects. The problem is that they have to different materials (one blue, one white). The result I get right now is this:[image: this]
The result I'd like to get is a clear, round curve seperating the blue and the white object. This model was created from a friend in Solid Edge and imported via stl, which is the reason why sometimes (like this time) the mesh is just bad (and always just triangles)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to add Solidify modifier to the blue mesh and direct thickness outwards. The other way would be to add Boolean modifier to the grey mesh, duplicate the blue mesh, set one of the blue meshes as Object in the modifier and choose Operation Difference. The boolean modifier must be first before edge split modifier.

Comment: I've already tried the boolean modifier (though I haven't applied it). The issue is the same. But thanks for the first tip. It worked just fine!